# Jail/Sandbox process on an overlay root and track changes

Tags: linux, process, overlayfs, jails, sandbox

### What I am trying to achieve

I want to run a process as an unprivileged user, but all files that are changed by this process should be only changed in a shadow folder. Furthermore, I want to disable networking capabilities if needed.

### What I have already tried

- mount overlay with lowerdir `/` and upperdir `/temp/fakeroot`, `unshare -rn`, `chroot /temp/overlay`

  - Problems: requires root for mount, overlay ignores nested mounts (my home directory)
- `unshare -rmn`, mount overlay with lowerdir `/` and upperdir `/temp/fakeroot`

  - Problems: error while trying to mount because `/tmp` is a subfolder of `/`
- `fuse-overlayfs`, `unshare -rn`, `chroot`

  - Problems: works only on kernels > 5.16, nested mounts can be read but writing is not possible
  - Note: I would be ok with the kernel limitation, but the nested mounts make it not usable

### Alternatives that I know exist, but do not seem promising

- Overlayroot: needs to be mounted at startup and does not store change delta
- `overlayroot-chroot`: Based on above.
- mergefs for merging all file systems into one: can't see how this would be done
- using Docker: requires root, does not store change delta

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: Mbox (https://github.com/tsgates/mbox) would seem promising but has not been updated since 2014.

Comment: `unshare -rn chroot` is not a sandbox as root can escape `chroot`. You need `pivot_root` followed by `umount`.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution combining multiple of the above-mentioned commands.

1. `mkdir -p /tmp/overlay-test/{upper,workdir,mount}`
2. `unshare -- map-root-user --net --mount` or short `unshare -rnm`
3. `mount.mergerfs / /tmp/overlay-test/view -o use_ino,posix_acl=true` (the options are optional)
4. `mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/tmp/overlay-test/view,upperdir=/tmp/overlay-test/upper,workdir=/tmp/overlay-test/workdir /tmp/overlay-test/mount`
5. `mount --rbind /dev /tmp/overlay-test/mount/dev` and `mount --rbind /proc /tmp/overlay-test/mount/proc`
6. `chroot /tmp/overlay-test/mount /bin/bash`

The general idea is to use `unshare` to create an environment where the user (not root) can mount a file system. Afterthat mergerfs is used to combine all sub-mounts (like home in many distros) into a single folder. This single folder can than be used as a lowerdir for the overlay. In order to execute commands, `dev` and `proc` need to be mapped into the overlay folder. This is ok as these folders are not writable by the user anyway. Last but not least, the `chroot` can be executed to switch to the overlayed-merged-rootfs. All changes made there are only done one the `upper` directory. When done, don't forget to unmount all mounts for cleanup.

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna say you didn't look closely enough at mergefs options/capabilities. The real problem with it is that it's slow.